# An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild

Tags: node.js, electron, node-gyp, electron-rebuild

I am trying to rebuild my ElectronJS application with Sqlite3, I have installed Python, VS development tools but its still gives me the error:
**My Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron .",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
    },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.2.1",
    "sqlite3": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.10.1"
  }
}
```

and this is the error which i face:
[image]

Comment: try running `electron-builder` command first

Comment: Please can you help me to solve this problem by step wise:
How can I run the electron-builder command?

Comment: have u installed `Visual Studio` correctly?

Comment: follow this > https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows , you need to install glyp windows building tools

Comment: @namila007 Thank You so Much, This help me a lot..

Comment: Shall i add it as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild) it has mentioned following requirements ;

> What are the requirements? Node v6.0.0 or higher is required. Building
>   the native modules from source uses `node-gyp`, refer to the link for
>   its installation/runtime requirements.

you need to [install gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) (it will be installed by the electron-rebuild)
and [configure the build](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) tools for the operating system. Here is the building option for windows as mentioned on the docs

> **On Windows**
>
> Install the current version of Python from the Microsoft
>   Store package.
>
> **Option 1** Install all the required tools and configurations using
>   Microsoft's windows-build-tools using npm install --global
>   --production windows-build-tools from an elevated PowerShell or CMD.exe (run as Administrator).
>
> **Option 2** Install tools and configuration manually:
>
> Install Visual C++ Build Environment: Visual Studio Build Tools (using
>   "Visual C++ build tools" workload) or Visual Studio 2017 Community
>   (using the "Desktop development with C++" workload) Launch cmd, npm
>   config set msvs_version 2017 If the above steps didn't work for you,
>   please visit Microsoft's Node.js Guidelines for Windows for additional
>   tips.
>
> To target native ARM64 Node.js on Windows 10 on ARM, add the
>   components "Visual C++ compilers and libraries for ARM64" and "Visual
>   C++ ATL for ARM64".

Comment: hi thanks for the upvote, if your problem solved by this, you need to press the `tick` to accept it as an answer. gl

Comment: I've ticked it I'm new here on this platform So I don't know some of the functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

try upgrading your version of sqlite3 to v5.0.0

here is a more detailed explanation of the same error
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50112270/4722811

```
  "dependencies": {
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.0"
  }
```